# Websphere won't start

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-rad

I keep getting the following error on my IBM Websphere server

```
[4/22/15 16:20:35:203 EDT] 00000000 AdminTool     A   ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.processDefaultJvmOptions(LaunchCommand.java:1246)
at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromJavaProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:1200)
at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:617)
at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.init(LaunchCommand.java:362)
at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.<init>(LaunchCommand.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.initializeRepositoryAndLauncher(WsServerLauncher.java:424)
at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:279)
at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:269)
at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:274)
```

I have been to numerous forums and cannot seem to find an up to date answer. 
I know I have to run some sort of command. I am on Windows 7 so what is the command I am supposed to run to fix this and can I run this command in the Windows command prompt.

Comment: You need to provide more information. What version, how are you trying to start, is it fresh install, etc... This is too little data to tell. Check native_std* logs you may find something there.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exception is sometimes caused by corrupt serverindex.xml or server.xml files. Check for any of them that may be 0 bytes and restore from backup. If you don't have a backup creating a new profile will restore them.

Comment: where are those files located at? Here is the path to my server C:\Users\Public\WebSphere

Comment: I found both files and they are both fine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you solve it? I dont't think I have a corrupted file either...

Comment: In my case, the platform's DNS name had been changed.  I edited plugin-config.xml and every serverindex.xml in the WAS tree, replacing the old DNS name with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the serverindex.xml is having some size for it, check if the serverindex.xml file is corrupted by opening it using Notepad ++ or similar tool. The file you need to refer is: \config\cells\Node01Cell\nodes\Node01.

If there are no backups, it is possible to use one of the temp file from \wstemp\anonymous1493784328013\workspace\cells\Node01Cell\nodes\Node01

Hope it helps anyone having similar issues.