# ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: websphere

when i start the web sphere server getting below error

```
[4/10/17 20:56:16:804 IST] 00000001 WsServerLaunc E   ADMU3007E: Exception java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.processDefaultJvmOptions(LaunchCommand.java:1252)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromJavaProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:1206)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:624)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.init(LaunchCommand.java:368)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.<init>(LaunchCommand.java:268)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.initializeRepositoryAndLauncher(WsServerLauncher.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:277)

[4/10/17 20:56:16:804 IST] 00000001 AdminTool     E   ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.processDefaultJvmOptions(LaunchCommand.java:1252)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromJavaProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:1206)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:624)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.init(LaunchCommand.java:368)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.<init>(LaunchCommand.java:268)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.initializeRepositoryAndLauncher(WsServerLauncher.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:277)

[4/10/17 20:56:16:804 IST] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.processDefaultJvmOptions(LaunchCommand.java:1252)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromJavaProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:1206)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.setParamsFromProcessDef(LaunchCommand.java:624)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.init(LaunchCommand.java:368)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.launcher.LaunchCommand.<init>(LaunchCommand.java:268)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.initializeRepositoryAndLauncher(WsServerLauncher.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.runTool(WsServerLauncher.java:279)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.AdminTool.executeUtility(AdminTool.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerController.executeUtilityOnWindows(WsServerController.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.tools.WsServerLauncher.main(WsServerLauncher.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:277)

[4/10/17 20:56:16:820 IST] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU1211I: To obtain a full trace of the failure, use the -trace option.
[4/10/17 20:56:16:820 IST] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU0211I: Error details may be seen in the file: C:\Apps\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\startServer.log
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websphere won't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808125/websphere-wont-start)

Comment: `NullPointerException` from product code is very often a product issue.  You should open a PMR with IBM so they can resolve the problem.  Even if it is a configuration issue on your part, the error message should be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your question may already be answered here: [Websphere won't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808125/websphere-wont-start).  Also, if you see warning or error messages in the C:\Apps\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\server1\startServer.log and native_stdout(err).log files, please post them as they may better inform the cause of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the same answer from the other question related for your reference:

Check if the serverindex.xml is having 0 size. If not, check if the serverindex.xml file is corrupted by opening it using Notepad ++ or similar tool. The file you need to refer is: \config\cells\Node01Cell\nodes\Node01.

If there are no backups, it is possible to use one of the temp file from \wstemp\anonymous<>\workspace\cells\Node01Cell\nodes\Node01

Hope it helps.